# CKEditor in CRM - SCRIPT5011 error "can't execute code from a freed script"

Tags: ckeditor, dynamics-crm

We use CK editor in a number of CRM organisations and it works fine in some. However in a specific one we keep getting this error that we don't see an obvious fix for:

[image]

- Refreshing the page > the editor loads fine
- Any fresh page load > the ckeditor throws the error below
- Stripping other custom javascript on the page didn't have any impact

The editor on the right is the initial page load, the one on the left is after a refresh:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cause was calling the editor twice in javascript, it would try to replace the placeholder it had already replaced and fail.